# "What was it your name was?"

Tags: phrases, idiomatic-language

If someone has already told me their name, but I forgot what it was, so I ask: "What was it your name was?"

Is that natural? And what else could I ask?

Comment: "Oh I am so sorry, will you please remind me of your name?"

Comment: I can imagine someone saying that even though it's illogical (the person's name hasn't changed) and not very polite. Another alternative would be, "I'm sorry, I've forgotten your name".

Comment: It doesn't imply that the name has changed -- saying that I would like to be reminded just says I don't remember it. Nothing illogical there that I can see. And the only thing I see wrong with OP's original statement is that it's a bit awkward in construction.

Comment: As Kate says, it is rude. People can be quite sensitive about having their name forgotten, as if they did not make much of an impression on you. You say "what was your name?" to someone you consider unimportant, and it shows.

Comment: Just: *What was your name?* Forget about the *it* and the second *was*.